# how to Parse json data into a chef recipe attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

How to parse a json output from a rest curl command as an attribute value in the default.rb file

Use Case:

In the Chef recipe Attributes --> attributes.rb file has the following default attributes which will be consumed by my recipe and these values needs to be randomly generated using a curl command which outputs it in form of a json output

```
default['agent']['id'] = 'F73D3CA4-!#!#-653A-XXXX-BBBBBB'
default['agent']['token'] = '90F1C7EA-*()*-YYYY-2528-ZZZZZZ'
```

This value is used in the recipes --> act.rb 
Syntax used

```
tenant_id                       = node['agent']['id']
token                           = node['agent']['token']
```

The recipe makes use of the tenant_id and token in the following way in the recepie

```
dsa_args << " \"tenantID:#{tenant_id}\" \"tenantPassword:#{token}\""
```

The curl command to get the the id and token is:

```
curl  --insecure -X GET -H "content-type: application/json"  -H 
"Accept: application/json" -d '{}' 
https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX/rest/bat/rant/tenant? 
name=Ante%20Data%20Wortyu%20Details
```

The Output is in the below format

{"id":"16","name":"Ante Data Wortyu Details","state":"ACTIVE", "tenantID":"F73D3CA4-!#!#-653A-XXXX-BBBBBB","tenantPassword":"90F1C7EA-*()*-YYYY-2528-ZZZZZZ"}

How would one pass the json formated output into my Chef Recipe or to the attributes file.

I went through the below link to get it completed but it fails with unauthorised errors:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/4-ways-to-parse-a-json-api-with-ruby.html

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure the request returns valid JSON data? e.g: _tenantID_ and _tenantPassword_ must be around quotes in the response

Comment: The output is not valid JSON: tenantID and its value are not surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Made changes, Copy/Paste missed the values " " : ""

Comment: include the test request and your code to implement the solution with the net http class thanks

Comment: @ Fabrizio Bertoglio, Do u have a sample that i could refer tooo.......

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat contrived and might not suit your entire use-case, but is an example of how you could parse the response body of an HTTP request as JSON and use it for Chef attributes.

```
# recipes/something.rb
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

jsonResponse = JSON.parse(RestClient.get(URL))
node.override['agent']['id'] = jsonResponse["tenantID"]
node.override['agent']['token'] = jsonResponse["tenantPassword"]
```